# How to handle duplicate columns in multiple WITH clause SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a query with multiple `WITH` clause in `bigquery`. I am getting an error : `Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s):` because I have some repeated columns in the tables.

Problem is I can't remove them as I need it to display in my table also they are needed in the `group by` clause in the tables.

My code somewhat looks like this:

```
WITH table0 as (## query0),
table1 AS (## query1),
table2 as (## query2),
table3 as (## query3),
table4 as (## query4),
table5 as (## query 5)
select
  *
from
  table0,
  table1,
  table2,
  table3,
  table4,
  table5
```

How do I handle duplicate columns in multiple `WITH` clause in `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a Cartesian product of the subqueries?

In any case, BigQuery gives you more control over the columns than other databases.  So, if `col1` is common to `table0` and `table1`, you can do:

```
select t1.*, t2.* except (col1)
```

If you want to keep both values:

```
select t1.*, t2.* except (col1), t2.col1 as t2_col1
```

or

```
select t1.* except (col1),
       t2.* except (col1),
       t1.col1 as t1_col1,
       t2.col1 as t2_col1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I try in the end `select  table0.*, table1.*, table2.*, table3.*, table4.*, table5.* except (col)` I get an error: `Unrecognized name: table0 at `. Probably because `bigquery`  doesn't recognize `table0.*` ?

Comment: The `except` has to be applied to each `*` reference, as shown in this answer.

Comment: Sorry didint quite get you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff means that in every table that's interest you, you should apply the except (col). It is not something general at the end of your select. Should be defined directly.

Answer (score 0):

From your previous question (that looks like was deleted) I think I remember your use case and there you had (I can be wrong ) only fields that are used for JOINs are "duplicate"
In such cases you can use below approach (in below example it is assumed that those duplicate fields are `id` and `day`)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table0` 
JOIN `project.dataset.table1` USING(id, day)
JOIN `project.dataset.table2` USING(id, day)
JOIN `project.dataset.table3` USING(id, day)
```

for example in below super-simplified dummy example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table0` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '2019-01-01' day, 0 col0
), `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '2019-01-01' day, 1 col1
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '2019-01-01' day, 2 col2
), `project.dataset.table3` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '2019-01-01' day, 3 col3
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table0` 
JOIN `project.dataset.table1` USING(id, day)
JOIN `project.dataset.table2` USING(id, day)
JOIN `project.dataset.table3` USING(id, day)
```

result will be

```
Row id  day         col0    col1    col2    col3     
1   1   2019-01-01  0       1       2       3
```

w/o any complains about duplicate fields

As you can see from above example  - using `USING()` instead of `ON` "magicaly" resolves the issue - but again - note - only for case when "duplicate" fields are all JOIN fields

Comment: Hi @mikhail thanks for your reply. Looks like your solution is very close to what I am asking for. But my duplicate field is just a field called `event_date` which is present in `table2` and `table5`. How should I approach in that case?